# Multiple Merges in Pandas

Tags: python, merge, pandas, dataframe

New to Python and Pandas, am working on a linear regression problem to predict salaries for UK job postings.

The job posting data frame (loaded from a .csv file) contains a column called 'Normalized Location' which simplifies the location data to a single place (i.e. if the actual posting's location was 'Glasgow, Scotland' the normalized location would be 'Glasgow').

There is a separate data frame that contains location trees with columns going from larger to more specific geographies.

E.g. there is a tree for Glasgow that is 'UK,Scotland,Glasgow', though there are also trees for more specific locations within Glasgow like 'UK,Scotland,Glasgow,Muirhead'

There are 6 location tree columns total which I have labeled UK,Region, Sub-Region,County, City, Borough/Neighborhood.  What I need to do is merge the location tree columns with the job listings data frame.  The normalized location column in the job listings data frame contains a mix of different geography types (e.g. some listings just say UK, some are just the region, and some are very specific London neighborhoods).

Ideally I'd like to have each job listing data frame to have 6 additional columns, if the normalized location is just 'UK' I'd like the UK column to have 'UK' and the other columns (region, sub-region, etc.) have the string 'Unknown'.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I opened both files with pd.read_csv (they're both comma delimited, the job listings were stored as 'data', the locations were stored as 'location')

I tried doing a series of merges:

merged_data = data.merge(location, how='left', left_on='LocationNormalized', right_on='UK')

Comment: Sorry not used to the markup here

`merged_data = data.merge(location, how='left', left_on='LocationNormalized', right_on='UK').merge(location, how='left', left_on='LocationNormalized', right_on='Region')`

and so on for the remaining location categories.  My thinking was to merge on the most abstract location first and then move to more specific location categories to merge the LocationNormalized values that are more specific.

Comment: The assignment is from a kaggle competition so here's the data for reference: http://www.kaggle.com/c/job-salary-prediction

Comment: At the very least I'd like to have all job listings have location data on the same 'level', e.g. I'd like to have 'Region' (note this is my definition of the second level of location tree data and isn't explicitly labeled such) so that I can add it as a feature to my model that has 8-10 categories vs. the normalizedlocation feature now which is a mix of all different location types (in the 10K test entries, there are hundreds of unique location values).